# How to correctly use JSDoc with Closure Compiler to rename properties identically?

Tags: google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

I have a function that takes dictionary-like object and has to extract one specific property and iterate over the possible nested childs:

```
function process(obj){

    //extract ID
    let secret = obj.secret;
    delete obj.secret; // yes, I have to delete that property, not just set to null

    // do some stuff

    if (Array.isArray(obj.others)) {

        // Extract others
        let others = obj.others;
        delete obj.others; // yes, I have to delete that property too

        // Process children too
        others.forEach(foo);
    }
}
```

I use this function to process objects:

```
class MyClass {

    contructor() {
        //init
    }

    getDictionary() {

        return {
            secret: 123,
            baz: 'baz',
            bar: 'bar',
            others: [{
                    secret: OtherClass,
                    forbar: 'foobar',
                    others: [{...},...]
                },{
                    ...
                }]
        };
    }

    parse() {
        return process(this.getDictionary());
    }
}
```

Closure Compiler always renames "obj.secret" in *process* function to (something like) "a.a", but not always renames the "secret" property in objects returned by *getDictionary*. If so, they do not have renamed the "secret" property identically.

I do not want to export those - *obj['secret']* : I want them to be renamed. I was looking for JSDoc annotations in [Closure Compiler guide](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler), but I'm not sure how to do that.

Especially how to define dictionary, that have mandatory "secret" property (type: number or some class), optional "others" property (is array of same-structured dictionaries) and zero or more string properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 Options:

### Disable Type Based Optimizations

Set the `--use_types_for_optimization=false` flag. Any property of the same name will be renamed consistently - whether they seem related or not.

### Implement an Interface

Give the compiler enough type information so that it recognizes the properties are related and must be renamed consistently:

```
/** @interface */
function MyDictionary() {}

/** @type {number} */
MyDictionary.prototype.secret;

/** @type {MyDictionary} */
MyDictionary.prototype.others;
```

Then add type annotations to your other code:

```
/** @return {MyDictionary} */
getDictionary() { ... }

/** @param {MyDictionary} obj */
function process(obj){ ... }
```

You may need to type cast the returned object from the `getDictionary` method as well.